# extract loop values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am having a piece of code in lightning component controller as follows.

```
for(var phone in component.find("phoneNumber")) { 
var phoneList=component.find("phoneNumber")[phone].get("v.value");
    alert(phoneList); 
}
```

Here `component.find("phoneNumber")` is an `lightning:input` and when the loop runs I get two values like 8762727211 and 8549502222. I want to capture the two phone Number values into say variable and then do some comparison. Please let me know how I can do this.

Comment: can you give more details like what type of comparison? because there might be any number of inputs - not just 2

Comment: @salesforce-sas, if the two phone values are the same then I will show some error message ,if the second Phone Number is null or empty then I will show some error message

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript functions like `find` and `map` to do that. Please below the sample code. Note that I mentioned the importance of each line in code itself for you to understand:

You should use [attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) like `required` and `messageWhenValueMissing` (and other messages) for more configured validity checks.

cmp file:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="phoneNumber" 
                 type="tel" 
                 label="Basic phone field"
                 required="true"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="phoneNumber" 
                 type="tel" 
                 label="Basic phone field"
                 required="true"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="phoneNumber" 
                 type="tel" 
                 label="Basic phone field"
                 required="true"/>

<lightning:button label="Check" onclick="{!c.check}" />
```

and its JS:

```
({
    check: function (component, event, helper) {
        let phoneNumberEls = component.find("phoneNumber"); // getting the array of elements
        if(phoneNumberEls.find(el => !el.checkValidity())) {
            alert("not valid"); // ideally should use toast message or any other custom logic but not alert
            return; // do not go further as input(s) are invalid
        }
        let phoneNumbers = phoneNumberEls.map(el => el.get("v.value")); // collect the phone-numbers if all inputs are valid
        let duplicatePhone = phoneNumbers.find(no => phoneNumbers.indexOf(no)!=phoneNumbers.lastIndexOf(no));
        if(duplicatePhone) {
            alert("duplicate => "+duplicatePhone); // ideally should use toast message or any other custom logic but not alert
            return; // do not go further as you found duplicates
        }
        alert("All are valid"); // remove alert and run business logic if all validations above are fine
    }
});
```

**Note:**

Although mentioned in code, do not use `alert` or `console.log` in actual code. This is only for you to understand. Implement actual business logic.